# How to link OpenSSL engine with a third party dynamic library

Tags: makefile, openssl, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a custom shared object file as an OpenSSL engine and it is working fine with pthread. I was trying to use a third-party [thread](https://github.com/stonebuddha/uthread) library instead of pthread. However, upon linking and running the engine, I'm getting a Segmentation fault. I just could not figure out why. I have a hunch that my linking with the newly built dynamic library is not correct,

Following is what I did

1. `Makefile` to create a dynamic library

   ```
   CC      = GCC
   CFLAGS  = -Wall -fPIC -g -O3 -MD
   LDFLAGS = -shared
   OBJ     = uthread.o

   all: libuthread.so

   libuthread.so: $(OBJ)
        $(LD) -shared -o $(@) $(OBJ)

    clean:
        rm -f *.o *.d libuthread.so

    -include *.d

    %.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
   ```
2. Copy `libuthread.so`  library to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`
3. My `Makefile` to compile my OpenSSL engine

   ```
   gcc -g -fPIC -c -fomit-frame-pointer testengine.c
   gcc -g -shared -o libtestengine.so rsa-engine.o rsa/rsa.o rsa/bignum.o 
   rsa/aes.o -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-Bdynamic -lcrypto -luthread
   mv libtestengine.so rsaEngine.so
   ```
4. After compilation, `$ldd rsaEngine.so`  shows the following,

   ```
   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffded367000)
   libcrypto.so.1.1 => /opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f895c5fa000)
   libuthread.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuthread.so (0x00007f895c3f4000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f895c02a000)
   libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f895be26000)
   libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f895bc09000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f895cd56000)
   ```

I use gdb to find out what causes the `segmentation fault`, and I find out that `uthread_join()`, is failing at some point. Can someone please tell me what I'm, doing wrong?

N.B: I checked the library with a simple program and the library works fine.

Comment: I don't see any justification for your hunch, here: I see no reason to assume it's related to linking in any way.  It seems like just a bug in your code.  `uthread_join()` is not a standard library function and it's not part of openssl, it appears to be part of the `uthread` library whatever that is, and your code is apparently using it incorrectly.

Comment: To try to fix it you should break out your trusty debugger and figure out why you're seeing a SEGV (that usually means you're trying to dereference a null pointer, or using freed memory, or some other similar memory violation).

Answer (score 0):

> I just could not figure out why.

There could be a number of reasons:

1. A threading bug in your code (which happens not to cause a crash with system libpthread library, but causes a crash with `uthread.o`, whatever it is),
2. A bug in `uthread.o` which is exposed by your test, but not by the simple program you tried,
3. A bug somewhere else.

There is no way for *us* to tell with the info provided.

Your first step should be to run the program under debugger and figure out *where* it crashes, and then *why*.

> I have a hunch that my linking with the newly built dynamic library is not correct

I have a hunch that your hunch is wrong. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your linking.